# iCloud log in requires old phone number i neither have nor remember

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts

I recently got rid of my iPhone & tried to log in via icloud on my laptop so I could get some contacts.

I know my Apple ID  & my password well. However, on entering my credentials,  iCloud requires that I either enter my old number which I dont recall nor still posses.

Is there a work around for this? or am I doomed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start an account recovery here : https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid

However, they may also ask you to verify your phone number and in this case, only [Apple support](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=psp&PRKEYS=PF23) can help you. They'll ask you question about your devices, your credit card and will ask you your new phone number.